# Is there a way to debug a refrenced package in Blazor WebAssembly when I have the symbols?

Tags: debugging, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I run my onw nuget server for shared code I am using. When debugging blazor webassembly either via visual studio or via chrome (shift alt d), I only see the files in my assembly, not the referenced ones via nuget. I do have the symbols and the sources. Is there a way to debug step into those ?

Comment: Hi, did you found a way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I can get to the IL code but thats of course not very helpful